# How to create FiltersAggregation query using JEST builders?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

How can I create `FiltersAggregation` query using JEST `AggregationBuilders` or similar? I looked at `FiltersAggregationIntegrationTest` but query part is defined directly by JSON and I need something more like `AggregationBuilders` (as I'm using this for standard term aggregation for example)

Link to `FiltersAggregationIntegrationTest`: 
https://github.com/searchbox-io/Jest/blob/master/jest/src/test/java/io/searchbox/core/search/aggregation/FiltersAggregationIntegrationTest.java

Answer (score 0):

I've one possibility:

```
FilterAggregationBuilder testFilter = AggregationBuilders.filter("test");
testFilter.filter(FilterBuilders.typeFilter("typeName"));
new SearchSourceBuilder().aggregation(testFilter);
```

This is a filter by Type, but the FilterBuilders has a termFilter too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that may work, I've cross posted this to the Jest github issue as well.

```
QueryBuilder filterTermsQuery = QueryBuilders.termsQuery("fieldName", "value1", "value2", "value3");
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = SearchSourceBuilder.searchSource()
    .query(boolQueryBuilder)
    .size(0)
    .aggregation(
        AggregationBuilders
            .filter("filterAggName") // returns FilterAggregationBuilder
            .filter(filterTermsQuery));
```

The gist is that you want to create a search source builder to use in the jest client, and supply that with and aggregation (which could also include sub-aggregations by chaining sub-aggregations on the `AggregationBuilders` method). Then define an aggregation of *filter* type available in `AggregationBuilders`. This returns a new builder of `FilterAggregationBuilder` where you can provide any QueryBuilder as the filter aggregation type. According to documentation, the `.filter(termsQuery)` call will cause only the documents that match the filter to fall into the bucket of this filter.

Hopefully this will resolve your issue unless I misunderstood your use case.